# vscode on WSL - Chrome debug failing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, chrome-debugging

I'm brand new to JS development and just started an introduction to JavaScript course.

I've edited this question as I have tried different approaches

I'm trying to use my Windows 10 machine with [Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2 (WSL2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) installed. I have a working python development setup but I've completely failed at getting a working JS dev setup where I can hit F5 and run a Chrome debugging session.

Having search around for hours, I when back to basics and all I'm not trying to do is get a working debug session for a basic `index.html` file. Can anyone spot what I have wrong?

Currently, the following `launch.json` does launch a Chrome browser but I see `This site can't be reached` in the browser window.

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch localhost",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost/index.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]}
```

Also tried this config:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch localhost",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
    }
]
```

}

I have the Debugger for Chrome installed - v4.12.12

In vscode DEBUG CONSOLE I see this error when I hit run: `crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.`.

I've also tried this with and without my Bitdefender firewall running just in case it was at fault, same result.

*UPDATE*

- Installed "Remote Development" extension in VSCode, in addition to "Remote - WSL".
- Node.js debug works fine... but I really want Chrome or FireFox to work
- Tried swapping the word `localhost` for the IP address... still nothing.
- New *file* launch config, see above, new error: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///__vscode-remote-uri__/home/USER/JS-dev/index.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is:

1. Install the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension. This installs it under the `WSL: UBUNTU - INSTALLED` section of the the VSCode extensions drop down area.
2. Edit the Live Server extension `settings.json` file to set `chromeDebuggingAttachment`to true, like this:     `"liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": true`
3. Click "GoLive" from the status bar as noted in the Live Server readme. This puts my `index.html` file in a browser tab.
4. To run a Chrome debug session from the menu `Run --> Start Debugging` or `F5` and it works.

Some useful notes:

- My `settings.json` is located here: `C:/Users/<MY-USER>/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json`.
- It works with the following `launch.json` file:

  ```
    {
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:5500/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]}
  ```
- The Live Server extension was last updated in 2019, so not great. I think this makes my solution a bit of a hack.
- Considering all the options I tried, my only explanation for this not working in my case is that the Remote Development extension currently states WSL2 support is experimental.